# Determine the primary index of a table in Teradata

Tags: indexing, teradata

Is there a command in teradata that returns which column in a table has been defined as the primary index? I didn't make some of the tables im working off of and trying to optimize my joins against those tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There's `dbc.IndicesV`, where `IndexNumber=1` indicates the PI and `dbc.PartitioningConstraintsV` for partitioning information.

For a single table Iprefer `SHOW TABLE tab;` because you get the full DDL including indexes & datatypes.

If you DBA's allow it you might also try `SHOW SELECT ....` to get the DDL od all obects used by that select.

Answer (score 3):

You can query DBC table to get this info..

```
SELECT
databasename, tablename, columnname, indextype, indexnumber, indexname
FROM  
dbc.indices
```